# Keyman version 16 requires "minimum engine version of 9.0"

Tags: version, custom-keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard for iPhone and Android for a community that wants to type their language on phones. I'm working on Windows 11 to create the keyboard, and I have downloaded both Keyman 16 and Keyman developer 16. When I try to compile the keyboard I made, I get an error message I don't understand:

> (114): 208A The compiler has assigned a minimum engine version of 9.0 based on features used in this keyboard

I don't know what I'm supposed to do, because I already have version 16 downloaded. My Windows version is also well above 9 (because I have 11). How can I solve this problem?

I'm unsure if this helps, but the symbols/diacritics I want on this keyboard are the following: a̠ e̠ i̠ u̠ o̠ ë̠ (and their capital letter versions).

Answer (score 0):

This is an informational message only, not an error. It means that your keyboard will work on Keyman 9.0 or any later version. Keyman 9 was released in 2014 -- so your keyboard is likely to be compatible for pretty much any Keyman user.